# Selenium, class could not be scrolled into view

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
   def wait(xpath):
        return WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))

   def find(xpath):
        try:
           element = wait(xpath)
        except:
            driver.quit()
       element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
       return element

      mail = find('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
      mail.clear()
      mail.send_keys('<the email>')
      mail_next = find('//*[@id="identifierNext"]')
      mail_next.click()

      password = find('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
      password.clear()
      password.send_keys('<the passwwordD>')
      password_next = find('//*[@id="passwordNext"]')
      password_next.click()
```

The error is " Element input class="whsOnd zHQkBf" name="password" type="password" could not be scrolled into view"

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', password)
```

Add this line before clicking event.
Hope this will help!

Comment: Can you explain me what is happening there, the page isn't scrollable and the password element is in view

Comment: can you share URL if possible to investigate